# Will unanswered questions with helpful comments be automatically deleted?

Tags: support, deleted-questions, unanswered-questions

I am aware that [unanswered questions with a score of 0 are automatically deleted after 30 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/auto-deleting-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006). Does this mean that those questions will be deleted even if they contain useful information that has been posted as a comment, instead of being posted as an answer?

I've noticed that some 0-score unanswered questions contain useful information that has been posted in comments instead of being posted as an answer, and I certainly don't want this information to be lost forever. For example, I got some useful advice from another user in [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16134270/putting-hyperlinks-in-source-code?noredirect=1#comment23048097_16134270), so I don't want my question to be automatically deleted even if its score never rises above 0.

Comment: Unanswered, zero-scored questions are deleted after **one year**. Unanswered, *negative-scored* questions are deleted after 30 days.

Comment: @Bart What qualifies as "something to indicate that it's useful"? Would a single upvoted comment be enough to save a question from automatic deletion, or would the comments be lost even if they had been upvoted?

Comment: Only if the question has a max of 1 comment

Comment: Unanswered zero-scored questions with **1 or 0 comments** and low views are deleted after 1 _year_.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards Does this mean that questions with at least one comment will never be automatically deleted?

Comment: Read the answer you link yourself.

Comment: No @AndersonGreen, it means that questions with a score of 0 or higher and at least one comment will never be automatically deleted...

Comment: If the information is useful why don't you take it and post it as an answer?!

Comment: @HugoDozois The comment doesn't directly answer the question, but instead offers a useful workaround for the problem, so I'm not sure if it would be appropriate to post it as an answer to that question.

Comment: Well a work around is still an answer you could put it as an answer telling it's a work around. An nothing obliges you to accept that answer, but it would offer the information in a clearer way than just comments

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that is exactly what it means.

If you feel the information is worth saving, improve the question, post an answer, raise the overall quality level, then it won't be deleted.